# Storing the Blog Post Title Or Lables as a String in Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

All I want is a code to get the title or label of the post store it in a string variable form.

I tried something like the below but not working :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   var getTitle=data:post.title;
   getTitle=getTitle.substring(0, getTitle.lastIndexOf(" Chapter"));
}
</script>
```

Using TryEditor from w3schools I executed this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button to locate the last occurance of a specified value.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var getTitle="Comic Title! Chapter 1";
getTitle=getTitle.substring(0, getTitle.lastIndexOf(" Chapter"));
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getTitle;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was successfully able to get only the part I want like and store it in getTitle like this :
Chuuko demo Koi ga Shitai!

This even worked correctly when I put the same above code in Blogger HTML Gadget and worked as it is.

Leaving that aside, what I wanted is instead of the highlighted part below,

> var getTitle=**"Comic Title! Chapter 1"**;

I tried this,

> var getTitle=**data:post.title**;

But it didn't work, **what should I do to get the title and store it in getTitle variable**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following data tag -

```
var getTitle = "<data:view.title/>";
```

This will return the title of the page being viewed (Will be different for different pages. Refer to this for more information - http://template-data.blogspot.com/2016/04/title_58.html )

> ### **title**
>
> Title of the current view.
>
> The title of the view is different for different views. For item
>   pages, it will be the post's title. For feed pages, it will be the
>   blog's title.
>
> ### title has data type string
>
> Strings are quote-wrapped sequences of characters.
>
> ### Metadata
>
> Metadata
>   are implicit properties belonging to a data type. If your data has the
>   name 'foo', you reference it with 'data:foo'. If the metadata is
>   'bar', you can reference the value of foo's metadata bar with
>   'data:foo.bar'.
>
> length: Provides the number of characters in the string.
>
> size: Same
>   as length.
>
> escaped: Provides the HTML escaped equivalent of the
>   string. This is useful when the string may represent user input, to
>   avoid HTML injection attacks
>
> jsEscaped: Provides the JS escaped
>   equivalent of the string. This is useful when the string may represent
>   user input, to avoid JS errors.
>
> jsonEscaped: Provides the JSON
>   escaped equivalent of the string. This is useful when the string may
>   represent user input, to avoid JSON errors.
>
> cssEscaped: Provides the
>   CSS escaped equivalent of the string.

The advantage of using the `data:view.title` tag is that it can be used anywhere inside the theme code without problems with the namespace being not defined. That said, it cannot be directly referenced from widget content (aka HTML/JavaScript, Text, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var getTitle = "<data:post.title>";
```

Or

```
var getTitle = &quot;<data:post.title>&quot;;
```

But you can only get `data:post.title` inside both of blog posts, popular posts and featured post widgets so it does't work with HTML widget.